# Error applying Security patch supee-6285

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, patches, supee-6285

I am trying to apply the latest magento security patch supee-6285 v2.

I get the following error message:

```
[root@dedivps-542 httpdocs]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
The next patch would create the file downloader/Maged/.htaccess,
which already exists! Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
patching file errors/processor.php
```

Previous patches have always installed ok. i have no technical knowledge in website coding etc so have no idea what the above error message means.

Can anyone please advise what the issue is?

Answer (score 4):

That's an easy one that I ran across on my first installation attempt on this patch.

`downloader/Maged/.htaccess` already exists, the patch can't deal with it and reports an unsuccessful patch run.

Simply delete `downloader/Maged/.htaccess` before running the SUPEE-6285 patch and it will run successfully and recreate the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I had the same problem with downloader/lib/.htaccess   Thanks for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Please check if `downloader` and `error` directories and below files are present in the magento root folder where you are trying to apply the patch.

```
downloader/Maged/Controller.php
downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
downloader/lib/.htaccess
downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
downloader/template/login.phtml
downloader/template/settings.phtml
errors/processor.php
```